# Combining 2 Javascript Regex Statements into 1

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way to combine these Javascript regex lines?

Both work fine. I was just wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing it.

```
type = type.replace(/\s+/g, '');  //removes space
type = type.replace('/', '');     // removes forward slash
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you only want to replace the *first* `/` as the 2nd replace does?

Comment: In my case, there will be only one /. However, I'd like to get rid of all of them, just to be safe. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
type = type.replace(/[\s/]+/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
type = type.replace(/\/|\s+/g, '');
```

Note how the `/` is escaped with a backward slash.

Answer (score 0):

```
type = type.replace(/[/\s]/g, '');
```

Comment: I suppose it's because \s existence makes it much easier to identify whitespace characters, than enumerating them.

Comment: Besides that it's also much better to use `\t` for tabs

Comment: =)), I just wanna make my answer dislike from other's. OK, i'm gonna chage it. :P